# Check checkboxes if present in json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox

I have this json object :

```
[{"id_distrib":"1"},{"id_distrib":"44"},{"id_distrib":"4"}]
```

I would like to check those checkboxes :

```
    <input id="1" class="cb_distrib_linux" type="checkbox" value="1">
Achlinux
<input id="2" class="cb_distrib_linux" type="checkbox" value="2">
Aurox
<input id="3" class="cb_distrib_linux" type="checkbox" value="3">
BackTrack
```

...
    
    CenOS 
...

I do that :

```
success: function(listes_distrib)
        {
           for(var distrib in listes_distrib)
           {

              $('#all_distrib_linux input:checkbox[value='+listes_distrib[distrib]+']').attr('checked', true);
           }
        },
```

All my checkboxes are checked.

An alert of listes_distrib[distrib] gives me "[" and not the id.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You have to select `id_distrib` attribute of `listes_distrib[distrib]`.

Comment: Why downvote this? It's certainly a valid enough question and the individual is showing a serious attempt to solve it. Maybe it was by some disco hater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#all_distrib_linux input:checkbox[value=' + listes_distrib[distrib].id_distrib +']').prop('checked', true);
```

You have to get the values from json objects using:

```
listes_distrib[0].id_distrib   // return 1
listes_distrib[1].id_distrib   // return 44
listes_distrib[2].id_distrib   // return 4
```

Also, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` as mentioned in [`.prop() API Documentation`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc):

> **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values
>   into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause
>   inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a
>   way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves
>   attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
success: function (listes_distrib) {
    $.each(listes_distrib, function (_, item) {
        $('#all_distrib_linux input:checkbox[value="' + item.distrib + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    })
},
```

Comment: Thannk you for your reply.